# how to get clicked cell index without using Column name of DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to get specific **clicked cell index** and Column name in DataGrid in WPF without using column name. I want to nave on behalf of  DataGrid cell value.

```
private void recordDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object val = recordDataGrid.SelectedValue;
    object ind = recordDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
    string stringval = val.ToString();
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(ind);
    MessageBox.Show(" " + n + "" + stringval);
}
```

Comment: You mean SelectedCells.Last().Column.DisplayIndex?

Comment: You have already provided the code. Is there anything wrong in this?